# Conditional formatting help request

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

After spending a couple days searching, I haven't found an answer that will let me apply a colour change rule that will change the text colour when the hyperlink exists in the page 'Master URL Sheet'.

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK(INDEX('Master URL Sheet'!$E:$E,MATCH(D2,'Master URL Sheet'!$B:$B,0)),Sheet!J2),Sheet!J2)
```

The above formula is used to create a hyperlink, format it so it displays a price from another sheet if the link does not exists or errors out.

The conditions are similar to what the index/match formula does already included in the formula for the cell.

So I have tried just using the following index formula to apply the colour change:

```
=index('Master URL Sheet'!$E:$E,MATCH(D2,'Master URL Sheer'!$B:$B,0))
```

I confirmed that when placed in a cell, generates the URL when it exists, but for as a rule to apply formatting, fails to produce a change in color to the text in the cell when the URL exists.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: It appears that Kris B's response -almost- works. Checked this by deleting the URL in the Master Sheet; which changed nothing, then deleted the item in referenced in $B:$B from the formula he posted, and in my own rule which then triggers the false condition, preventing the colouring of the cell.

Unfortunately I am stuck now, as this works if the item matching the B coloumn will trigger the change, and not matching the E column.

Comment: Have the original formula return a different value that's never used. Then check for that value. EG: 
=IF(IFERROR(HYPERLINK(INDEX('Master URL Sheet'!$E:$E,MATCH(D2,'Master URL Sheet'!$B:$B,0)),Sheet!J2),"Not Found")="Not Found","Hyperlink Not Found","Hyperlink Found")

Comment: Replace "Hyperlink Not Found" and "Hyperlink Found" with True/False to vary your result for conditional formatting.

Comment: Initial post updated to reflect additional findings.

Answer (score 0):

I found the help I need, posting the solution here to spread around.

```
=INDEX('Master URL Sheet'!$E$2:$E$1723,MATCH(D2,'Master URL Sheet'!$B$2:$B$1723,0))<> ""
```

Using this to check if the URL exists on the master url sheet, and inserting it as a conditional to change the colour when the field is not empty. Its good for my own purposes as I am the only one managing the sheet so I shouldn't have to worry about sabotage, unless its from myself.